# Strange Behaviour when not closing hibernate session

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf

I faced a problem regarding closing a hibernate session , The problem detail is:
UI(Implemented using JSF2.1 ) hangs after doing some action many times resulting with an empty request.  The cause of the problem is the hibernate session does not close after doing any database action

So my question why has this hanging happened ? why an empty request? I think when something like this happens an exception will like IllegalStateException would be thrown by hibernate API to tell you "you have a lot of sessions opened " right  ?

Comment: Do you mean action submits form twice?

Comment: No its submit it one time but when you repeat the action many time its stuck when open firebug from firefox you will see that empty request is sent each time you make any action on the UI

Comment: There is a known issue called double click problem, but your problem seems different. Can you post some code? Yur page may not be well formatted.

Comment: Yes i know the problem , i read about it.it called also idempotent requests , But not its too different from what iam facing here ,

Comment: Sorry I cant post the code because a regulation specified by that iam working with :S

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you don't close your Hibernate sessions and therefore do not release JDBC connections, you have what is typically called *Connection leak*. So, after a number of requests (depending on the size of your connection pool) the server will not be able to acquire a connection to respond your request. Actually, server will be waiting for connections to be released and be available on pool again and it will seem to be hanging.

Comment: What is the solution?